# Sudden drop in Google impression on Google Webmasters

Tags: seo, google-search-console

I am the developer of Infermap.com. We are regularly monitoring and working on SEO and presence on Google SERPs. In the past 3-4 days we have seen a sudden steep drop in the number of Impressions on Google.
 [image: Click to see the performance graph]

Can someone suggest me the possible reason of why might this happen and by what ways I can prevent it.

Also I have added around 11k urls to be indexed out of which only 1.5k has been indexed. What are the possible reasons for it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(note: this question should probably be moved to [Webmasters Stack Exchange](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/))

Looks like your 11k new URLs have not been picked up as quality content by Google. You might even be cloaking, when I click on a result I get a completely different text on your site.

[image: Google Results]

Ways to avoid it:

- avoid [cloaking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloaking)
- avoid adding similar looking pages without unique content, e.g. make sure your pages are unique enough before publishing them
- feed new content that looks alike gradually, e.g. start with 100 pages, wait a week or two, and add another 200. Once you are confident your pages are picked up well you can add everything at once.